# How to hide the element style in child style element?

Tags: android

I need to 'hide' the `textSize` parameter in `BigButton` style, inherited from `Button`. How to do so?

```
<style name="Button">
    <item name="android:background">@color/button_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/button_text_size</item>
</style>

<style name="BigButton" parent="@style/Button">
    <item name="android:textSize"></item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<style name="BigButton" parent="@style/Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">@null</item>
</style>
```